# Glide load local image by Uri.

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm trying to use Glide to load an image from local storage with no success.

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(pictureUri) // Uri of the picture
    .transform(new CircleTransform(..))
    .into(profileAvatar);
```

This is the error I get:

```
java.lang.Exception: Failed to load model: '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150831_180900.jpg'
at com.bumptech.glide.request.GenericRequest.onSizeReady(GenericRequest.java:441)
at com.bumptech.glide.request.target.ViewTarget$SizeDeterminer.getSize(ViewTarget.java:211)
at com.bumptech.glide.request.target.ViewTarget.getSize(ViewTarget.java:100)
at com.bumptech.glide.request.GenericRequest.begin(GenericRequest.java:272)
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestTracker.resumeRequests(RequestTracker.java:83)
at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.resumeRequests(RequestManager.java:180)
at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.onStart(RequestManager.java:203)
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.ActivityFragmentLifecycle.onStart(ActivityFragmentLifecycle.java:50)
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment.onStart(SupportRequestManagerFragment.java:135)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1986)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1051)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1179)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1996)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:176)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:517)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:6063)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6068)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2975)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: can you please check this link https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/155

Comment: I already did, but haven't found it to be that useful. Check my answer... if you make a File instance pointing to the Uri location, it works. It's weird.

Comment: I think already you got the solution , but here is the link to know best way to use glide. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39336438/3636561

Comment: Make sure you have added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> into your manifest and also you have performed runtime permission check if your `targetSdk >= 23`

Adding these solved the problem for me

Answer (score 122, accepted):

While waiting for someone to respond, I tried to make a `File` instance from the `Uri` and load that. It works! Weird!

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(new File(pictureUri.getPath())) // Uri of the picture
    .transform(new CircleTransform(..))
    .into(profileAvatar);
```

Comment: It works but avatars loading with small delay from asset folder somehow

Answer (score 14):

If you pass an `Uri` instance it better be compliant, it looks like yours doesn't have a schema (`file://`).

You can check how [`Uri`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/3.0/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/load/model/UriLoader.java#L30), [`String`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/3.0/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/load/model/StringLoader.java#L26) and [`File`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/3.0/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/load/model/FileLoader.java#L25) models are loaded to debunk the weirdness :)

Comment: To confuse even further with Android built-in traps for ineffective coding, when you use the built-in image chooser, programatically, it returns a string "content://.....", which is not readable by FileInputStream nor File. And Bitmapfactory.loadFile(uri) strips one of the slashes and grants a filenotfoundexception because the string is transformed (by Bitmapfactory) to "content:/…, i.e. one slash. 
So sad to see such stupid things in an operating system.

Answer (score 11):

If it is a file path, it can be passed directly.  Tested with Glide 4.8.0

```
 Glide.with(context)
  .load(pictureUri.getPath())
  .transform(new CircleTransform(..))
  .into(profileAvatar);
```

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that the Uri is from file.

```
Uri photoUri = Uri.fromFile( new File( preferences.getPhotoUrl()));

Glide.with(this).load( photoUri).into( civUserProfilePhoto);
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case I run Emulator on Android 10 , and due to security reason, legacy external storage access is `disabled` by default , 
So I add following code in `Androidmanifest` file

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" 
.....
.....

</application>
```

Make sure that you have included user permission to read and write external storage

Answer (score -1):

I try this without creating File object, it works fine.

```
public static void setImageUrlFromUri(ImageView imageView, String imageUrl) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
            Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    }
```