# using glide library android to load picture from gallery

Tags: java, android, image-processing, android-glide

I am using the Glide library in an android application, i have loaded a image into a circular view, i am loading the image from a url, would it be possible to let the user load their own image using glide, from their camera/gallery, and not from a URL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glide load local image by Uri.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332003/glide-load-local-image-by-uri)

Comment: thank you, will have a look