# How do I save image in imageview?

Tags: android

My app lets you pick an image from gallery and shows it in imageview, but when you close the activity and open it again the image is not there anymore.

```
  private final static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

public void getpic(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String selectedimage = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedimage));

    }


}
```

How can I save the picked image?

Comment: use bitmap.compress to save image in local

Comment: either store on web server or you can store it locally

Comment: you can store image path in shared preference and next time you open app.check if imagePath is there in shared pref then show image

Comment: Pls can you show me some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `Bitmap` from `ImageView` to save it:

```
imageview.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm=imageview.getDrawingCache();

OutputStream fOut = null;
Uri outputFileUri;
try {
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + File.separator + "folder_name" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
try {
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this immediately.

Comment: I could not make it work. Please can you show me how you do you access the file after you save it?

Comment: Have you provided permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` .  It  's in you External Storage folder called `folder_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide for loading image

add below dependencies in build.gradle(app)

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
```

add below code inside your onActivityResult

```
  Glide
  .with(mContext)
  .load(selectedimage)
  .centerCrop()
  .placeholder(R.color.black)
  .crossFade()
  .into(imageView);
```

For more details refer
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

http://en.proft.me/2016/09/12/load-process-and-cache-image-android-using-glide/

[Glide load local image by Uri.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332003/glide-load-local-image-by-uri)