# Fail to use Glide to load local disk image into home widget remote views

Tags: android, android-glide

I tried to use `Glide`, to load local disk jpg image into Home Widget.

However, I'm getting the following error, which I have no idea how to debug it.

```
Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to unparcel Bitmap
        at android.graphics.Bitmap$1.createFromParcel(Bitmap.java:1793)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap$1.createFromParcel(Bitmap.java:1784)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$BitmapCache.<init>(RemoteViews.java:1176)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.<init>(RemoteViews.java:2433)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.<init>(RemoteViews.java:2419)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$3.createFromParcel(RemoteViews.java:3865)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$3.createFromParcel(RemoteViews.java:3864)
        at com.android.internal.appwidget.IAppWidgetService$Stub.onTransact(IAppWidgetService.java:179)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
```

---

This is the code I used to load local disk image into `RemoteViews`

```
 // I had confirmed the path is accessible without permission required.
 // context is application context.
 RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(PACKAGE_NAME, R.layout.collage_view_row);
 AppWidgetTarget awt = new AppWidgetTarget(context, R.id.image_view_0, rv, appWidgetId);
 Glide.with(context)
    .asBitmap()
    .load("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.yocto.wenote/files/attachment/c52ba5f3-04fd-4ee8-a662-c058d83c96ff.jpg")
    .into(awt);
```

My layout file `collage_view_row.xml` is pretty straight forward.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="1dp"

        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/image_view_0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="1dp"

        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/image_view_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="1dp"

        android:id="@+id/image_view_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea how I can debug what's went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put "file://" before the location.

This might be helpful:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332003/glide-load-local-image-by-uri)